# Any way to exit bash terminal from anywhere but not quitting a script?

Tags: linux, bash, vim, vi

I am making the "quit" command in a script that will act like "exit" but will close down the running bash terminal.
The only way I know how to do quit is:

```
exit
```

but that does no good - it just takes it as an exit for the script, not the bash terminal session.

Comment: Is "ctrl-d" too hard to type?

Comment: What?  I'm confused, you can exit a shell no matter what directory you are in.  Is what you are trying to do, to create a command that will exit a session, even if you have processes in the background?  If so, man 'nohup'.  Also, what does this have to do with vim?

Comment: I am making a script in bash (in vim MODE) , so when i do make the mistake of typing quit instead of exit, it will do almost the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and kill the bash process by finding the process ID using `top` command and then `kill #ID`. This can end the bash session and keep the script running.

Comment: Okay,i will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to detach a script from the shell you're in. If you want to detach from the shell from within the script itself you can effectively fork it ie.

```
#!bin/bash
forked_function() {
  # This will now be in it's worn process. Check it using 
  # ps ax | grep forked_function
  sleep 1000;
}
forked_function &
```

A very common approach is to use `screen`. This enables you to `close` the terminal and come back to the running process later where you left off. If all you want to do is run a script then exit try using an ampersand appended to the script you are trying to run ie

```
script &
exit
```

That will leave chrome running but allow you to detach it it it won't close when you close the terminal. You can also manage the tasks in the background. Have a look at `man jobs`

```
script &
jobs
```

You can use commands like `fg 1` to bring job number 1 back to the foreground etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can try executing that command like you were a shell proccess:

```
execp("exit",NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: Okay,i will try this.